# String search by coincidence?

Tags: python, string, find-occurrences, string-search, multiple-occurrence

I just wanted to know if there's a simple way to search a string by coincidence with another one in Python. Or if anyone knows how it could be done.

To make myself clear I'll do an example.

```
text_sample = "baguette is a french word"
words_to_match = ("baguete","wrd")

letters_to_match = ('b','a','g','u','t','e','w','r','d')   #   With just one 'e'
coincidences = sum(text_sample.count(x) for x in letters_to_match)

#    coincidences = 14 Current output
#    coincidences = 10 Expected output
```

My current method breaks the `words_to_match` into single characters as in `letters_to_match` but then it is matched as follows: "**baguette** is **a** f**re**nch **w**o**rd**" (`coincidences = 14`).

But I want to obtain (`coincidences = 10`) where "**baguet**t**e** is a french **w**o**rd**" were counted as coincidences. By checking the similarity between `words_to_match` and the words in `text_sample`.

How do I get my expected output?

Comment: so you only want the count to include the first occurence of each character? But in your output "e" is the only character that's counted twice. I don't get the logic here

Comment: No, if text_sample was "a baguette is a french word" that first 'a' would be matched as the first occurrence and that's not what I want. I want it done by checking the similarity between words_to_match and the words in the text_sample.

Comment: That sounds very wage to me as well. Is it something in the direction of [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) that you are out after?

Comment: Exactly like edit distance, is there a way to do it on python?

Comment: I'm sure you can find a Python implement of a function that calculates the Levenshtein distance or one of the other measurement techniques somewhere (or implement one of them yourself).

Comment: @Pomodor0 You might also want to take a look at [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)

Answer (score 1):

first, split words_to_match with

```
    words = ''
    for item in words_to_match:
        words += item
    letters = [] # create a list
    for letter in words:
        letters.append(letter)
    letters = tuple(letters)
```

then, see if its in it

```
    x = 0
    for i in sample_text:
        if letters[x] == i:
            x += 1
            coincidence += 1
```

also if it's not in sequence just do:

```
    for i in sample_text:
        if i in letters: coincidence += 1
```

(note that some versions of python you'l need a newline)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need the length of the longest common subsequence (LCS). See [the algorithm in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Computing_the_length_of_the_LCS) for computing it. You may also be able to find a C extension which computes it quickly. For example, [this search](https://pypi.org/search/?q=longest%20common%20subsequence) has many results, including [pylcs](https://pypi.org/project/pylcs/). After installation (`pip install pylcs`):

```
import pylcs
text_sample = "baguette is a french word"
words_to_match = ("baguete","wrd")
print(pylcs.lcs2(text_sample, ' '.join(words_to_match.join)))  #: 14
```